# How to properly mock ES6 class dependencies

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app

I'm struggling getting mocking to work for service classes that my React components depend on - classes that are initialized inside of the components. I'm using the Jest "manual mock" method. I'm making the call to `jest.mock`, but every time I run the tests, they use the real service class and not the mock.

I've seen it suggested that what I'm trying to do (in the example below, mock out `UserService`) isn't possible with Jest. I understand that in this example, the `getUsers` call could just be an exported function, but in my real projects I would have full classes that would need mocked; this is just an oversimplified example.

My question boils down to: Can I mock out a class like this in testing React components with Jest, and if so what am I missing? Here's an example of non-working mock.

Edit: Code now in GitHub: https://github.com/cvs-mrussell/ReactJestMockTest

Edit 2: If I convert my component to a class, the mock works. Issue with testing React hooks? Reading up on this, it looks like testing with async calls in `useEffect` can be tricky prior to React 18.9.0-alpha, at which point an async version of `act` was introduced specifically to address that scenario (ref: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14050#issuecomment-480272261). So, looks like I need to rework my test anyway due to the async issue, but doesn't answer why my mock isn't being used in this particular scenario (using hooks).

```
// /src/Services/UserService.ts
export default class UserService {
    public async getUsers(): Promise<IUser[]> {
        console.debug('Real getUsers');

        const response = await axios.get(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users);
        return response.data;
    }
}
```

```
// /src/Services/__mocks__/UserService.ts
export default class UserService {
    public async getUsers(): Promise<IUser[]> {
        console.debug('Mock getUsers');

        return Promise.resolve([
            { id: 1, name: 'User 1', email: 'email1' },
            { id: 2, name: 'User 2', email: 'email2' },
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import UserService from '../../Services/UserService';
import IHomeState from './IHomeState';
import IUser from '../../Interfaces/IUser';

const Home = (): JSX.Element => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        users: [],
    } as IHomeState);

    async function loadData(): Promise<void> {
        const service = new UserService();
        const users = await service.getUsers();

        setState({ users });
    }

    useEffect((): void => { loadData(); }, []);

    const userList = state.users.map((el: IUser): JSX.Element => (
        <li key={el.id}>
            {el.name}
        </li>
    ));

    return (
        <ul>
            {userList}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

```
// Test
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import UserService from '../../Services/UserService';
import Home from './Home';

jest.mock('../../Services/UserService');

it('renders without crashing', (): void => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to mock the function inline to check that you are doing everything else correctly, something like:

```js
// Test
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import UserService from '../../Services/UserService';
import Home from './Home';

const mockedGetUserFunction = async (): Promise<IUser[]> => { /* implement mock */ };
jest.mock('../../Services/UserService');
mockedGetUserFunction.bind(UserService);

it('renders without crashing', (): void => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

Also, try avoiding exporting your service as default (this will need you to adjust your imports afterwards):

```
export default class UserService => export class UserService
```

Comment: No go... I added the logic to return a fake list of users where you have "implement mock". Test runs and passes, but it's still using the real service class, not the mocked function. I also changed the service class so it's no longer a default export.

Comment: mmm have you also tried removing the mock you made in `__mocks__`?

Comment: Just tried that... same result. I uploaded my code to GitHub if that would help, link is in the question above. I feel like there's something really simple/dumb I'm missing...